# TV provider disappeared from iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, television

Somewhat bizarrely, on both my iPhone and iPad, TV Provider is not an option in the Settings menu. If I search in Spotlight, it shows up, but when I click on it it just opens the Settings app (does not open TV Provider). It's a bit frustrating because I recently canceled my FiOS subscription and switched to Spectrum, but have no way of changing my TV provider settings in any of my apps.[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you see under "Game Center" in the Settings menu? On my iPhone, that's where I see "TV Provider" - just above the settings for each individual app.

Comment: I actually do not have Game Center (that is because of a content restriction from my work—but no such restriction for TV appears to exist)

Comment: How do you know they aren’t restricting it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see "TV Provider" in Settings sign in into both iCloud and AppStore app with the account that set US as a home location and reboot device.